# How can I view the number of concurrent HTTP requests being made by the server?

Tags: c#, api, concurrency, monitoring, task-parallel-library

I am using a third party API to query data asynchronously.  Here is an example of my code:

```
private void AsyncDataLoad() {
    Task[] tasks = new Task[6] {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff1()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff2()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff3()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff4()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff5()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchSomeStuff6())
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

How can I view how many requests I have open at one time?  By default I think there is a limitation to the number of concurrent requests I can have open on one domain and I would like to change this.  But, I want to be able to prove this is the fact before trying to make any changes.

My development box is on Windows 7 Enterprise if that helps for any tool suggestions.  I tried using PerfMon, but, it didn't seem like any properties available for monitoring with that tool were picking up HTTP requests made by the server.

Comment: TcpView (sysinternals) and resmon (comes with Win7) can show connected sockets, although they don't capture the calls to the extent of HTTP-specific fiddler. :)

Answer (score 0):

IME, fiddler is the best tool for viewing http call behavior. Its timeline lets you view concurrency nicely.

The setting for changing the limit is in connectionManagement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to manually watch it yourself (not inspect it programatically), then you could use [TCPView from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).